# Only run workflow if semantic version is used

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows I'd like to run. One, if a regular semver release tag is pushed to my repo, for example `v2.3.2`, and a second one to create a pre-release when something that contains `release` in the version is pushed, e.g. `v2.3.2-release.2`. Other tags that don't follow either pattern should not run.

The one that targets the prerelease works well, I accept all tag names and I run an if statement if `release` is in the name of the tag, like so:

```
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/tags
    tags:
      - '**' # Accept all tag pushes, and filter them out beyond that.

name: Create Prerelease

jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: linux
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Create Prerelease ️
        # Only tag prereleases if the tag name includes release
        if: contains(github.ref, 'release')
        id: create_prerelease
        uses: actions/create-release@v1

        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: true
```

Where I run into problems, however, is making sure that only the `v2.3.2` pattern runs in the second workflow.

```
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/tags
    tags:
      - 'v*' # Push events to matching v*, i.e. v1.0, v20.15.10. Used for Semvar releases.

name: Create Release

jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: linux
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Create Release ️
        id: create_prerelease
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

How can I adjust the second workflow so it works correctly? Is there a way I can filter the `on.push.tags` name based on a regex pattern here that'll work?

Comment: See [Filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet). Something like `'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'` should work in your case.

Comment: You can also combine both workflows into one and only toggle the relevant parts using expressions. Here's an [example](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJyNkUtOwzAQhvc+xSxQzSvhsSOrigoBQgKEygqhykkmTWiwIz8SpLZnqMSWBceAW8ERcBPTBCRQvbE988/n8fyCBwSgMCpd7gCajVVzAvCAlnf73tH9jv9j26aEcPaIAWxMpxAJrlnG1eY406kJfYnJLlCJOTKFdAt6PaDXEinMZkApzOc3TYqQBxHWb4Umy+Pm0QY7kMg01nQHrYScJLmobHmtk4YrT/AA8oybpzqkNBad1h0pxWgijIaBiBE+X1+enQDAKFQBsEhngqu9yAn75SH5zfivG8tcvH28L/7C1rWem0a/PFjpkJfB6gJwej48uz0eDa8uTi6buSq0xVr53cz395ersr10Cda5UetKa0a3xg6u6WQNZSxZogNIWG69asOFRMdYz37L/AKsDLdI) (not tested).